# Ubuntu installation got hanged

Tags: installation, dual-boot

This is my first ever attempt at working with Ubuntu. I only installed Windows in the past.. I purchased new hardwares this week and I would really like to give Ubuntu a chance (especially since I don't want to buy another Windows license).

The hardware specifications:

**Processor:**  AMD FX-8150 Zambezi 3.6GHz Socket AM3+ 125W Eight-Core Desktop Processor

**Motherboard:** ASUS Crosshair V Formula AM3+ AMD 990FX SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX AMD Gaming Motherboard

**Hard disk 1:** SAMSUNG 830 Series MZ-7PC128D/AM 2.5" 128GB SATA III MLC Internal Solid State Drive (SSD). This is my boot drive

**Hard disk 2:** Western Digital VelociRaptor WD5000HHTZ 500GB 10000 RPM SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive - This is a backup drive where I installed Windows Vista, until I can get Ubuntu to work.

**Memory:** G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 16GB (2x8GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM

**Graphics Card:** ASUS HD7850-DC2-2GD5 Radeon HD 7850 2GB 256-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16

I have downloaded and tried to install both Ubuntu 64 bit and Kubuntu 64 bit (both 12.04). Both always fail to copy a file during installation or get hanged during installation to SSD. I have burned two copies of Ubuntu 12.04 and both CD failed

I have installed Vista on the HDD drive. Is it possible to install the Ubuntu on that drive?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by removing one of the RAM during install.

Now I am attempting to get the ASUS HD7850 properly working.

Comment: Are you the same person as [the original poster of this question](http://askubuntu.com/users/72649/lokitez), using a different account? The wording of your answer suggests this, even though you've posted with a different user account.